# I can't find and fix the warning in my code

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, data-loss

```
void CNodo::DrawWithAnArrow(System::Drawing::Graphics^g, CNodo nd){
     g->DrawRectangle(System::Drawing::Pens::Black, posx, posy, lado, lado);
     System::String ^cadena = contenido.ToString();
     System::Drawing::Font ^f = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 10);
     g->DrawString(cadena, f, System::Drawing::Brushes::Black, posx +  static_cast<int>(lado / 4), posy + static_cast<int>(lado / 5)); // warning is in this line
     g->DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pens::Black, posx + lado, posy + (lado / 2), nd.getX(), nd.getY() + (lado / 2));
}
```

Greetings to everyone in this forum.

So. I receive a warning from the compiler indicating that there is a possible loss of data because there is a conversion from int to float.

I get confused because all the variables that are in my code are integers ( posx, posy and lado), where "lado" is equal to 20.

I even used a static_cast to prevent the warning, but it's still there.

If anyone can help me out with this problem, I'll really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The [Graphics.DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/349afwez%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes two float values for the x and y parameters. Try this:

```
static_cast<float>(posx + (lado / 4))
```

Please note that the `lado/4` expression might cause a precision loss.